# How to make react-grid-gallary horizontally scrollable?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, npm-package

I'm using [react-grid-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-grid-gallery).

Is there any way to use it as a horizontally scrollable gallery?

Is there any package available for such implementations? (having a horizontal gallery with a lightbox)

Comment: Well as the package is named, it's meant to be used as a grid. You can always mess with CSS to change it, but why fight it? I personally would just use CSS to do this with a regular block element or use flexbox but a quick google search I found this: https://reactjsexample.com/an-image-lightbox-component-for-reactjs/   which should do everything you want...

Comment: @Ginfuru Thank you so much. I'll look into it.